# Por qué el elemento no es centrado totalmente?

Tags: javascript

Cree una función en javascript ,para centrar un elemento. Pero el elemento está algo más a la izquierda, de hecho si inspecciono la consola de google chrome, sale que hay menos distancia en el lado izquierdo, cual es el error? si he calculado todo su tamaño, incluyendo el margen.?

```js
function a() {
    this.centerElement = e => {
        var bW = parseInt(document.body.scrollWidth, 10),
            w = e.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        eq = bW / 2 - w / 2;
        e.style.position = "absolute";
        e.style.left = eq + "px";
    };
}

var b = new a().centerElement(document.getElementById("elemento"));
```

```css
#elemento {
    border: 4px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id=elemento></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.outerWidth` en lugar de `.width` en la siguiente línea. Debido a que `.width` omite los padding y margin del elemento:

```
w = e.getBoundingClientRect().outerWidth;
```